# Is it possible to override Sphinx autodoc for specific functions?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using Sphinx's autodoc plugin to automatically document a set of modules.  I have a function that accepts `*args`, and I'd like to override the documentation to show the slightly nicer `funcname(arg1[, arg2[, ...]])` style that the Python stdlib docs use.

Is it possible to override the autodoc output for a specific function?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible to override a signature by using `autofunction`:

```
.. automodule:: yourmodule
   :members:
   :exclude-members: funcname

.. autofunction:: funcname(arg1[, arg2[, ...]])
```

However, the function with the overridden signature is not sorted with the other functions pulled in with `automodule`. Using explicit `autofunction` directives for every function works around that:

```
.. autofunction:: firstfunc

.. autofunction:: funcname(arg1[, arg2[, ...]])

.. autofunction:: thirdfunc
```

**Addition**

You can also append to the docstring:

```
.. autofunction:: funcname(arg1[, arg2[, ...]])

   Extra documentation here.
```

To override both signature and docstring, use `function` instead of `autofunction`.

**Addition 2**

The signature can also be overridden by having a signature as the first line of the function docstring. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12087750/407651) for details.

Comment: +1 for "Addition2". Overriding the signature in the doc string is much easier than try to exclude the member, then re-add it with custom signature, etc.