# Documenting with Sphinx python methods that do have default parameters with sentinel objects?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, default-parameters

If you want to be able to allow people to call some methods using `None` you have to do use a [sentinel object](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) when you define the method.

```
 _sentinel = object()
 def foo(param1=_sentinel):
     ...
```

This would allow you to call `foo(param1=None)` and be able to make the difference between a call like `foo()`.

The problem is that when Sphinx does document the method it will write something like

```
mymodule.foo(param1=<object object at 0x108c1a520>)
```

How can I convince Sphinx to have a user friendly output for these functions?

Note, Imagine how the documentations look if you have 3-4 parameters using the sentinel approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to persuade Sphinx to be more "friendly" as long as you have a sentinel that creates an object outside the function. Sphinx' autodoc extension [imports the module](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html), which means that module-level code is executed.

Are you sure you can't use something like this?

```
def foo(param1=None):
    if param1 == None:
        param1 = whatever you want...
    else:
         ...
```

Comment: sentinel is a one-off object outside function so that function can handle None values as a general case so I believe sorin really can't use what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled by manually specifying function signature in autodoc directive, e.g.:

```
.. automodule:: pymorphy.contrib.tokenizers

    .. autofunction:: extract_tokens(foo, bar)

    .. autofunction:: extract_words
```

Comment: Yes, this works: +1. Why didn't I think of it? :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365684

Answer (score 1):

The `<object object at 0x108c1a520>` part of generated method signature can be changed by overriding the `__repr__` method of the sentinel object.

```
_sentinel = type('_sentinel', (object,),
                 {'__repr__': lambda self: '_sentinel'})()
```

It will be rendered by Sphinx as something like this:

```
mymodule.foo(param1=_sentinel)
```