# Sphinx floating point formatting

Tags: python, formatting, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to generate documentation from code. Does anyone know if there is a way to control the formatting of floating point numbers generated from default arguments.

For example if I have the following function:

```
def f(x = 0.97):
    return x+1
```

The generated documentation ends up looking like:

```
foo(x = 0.96999999999997)
```

Obviously this is a floating point precision issue, but is there a way to make the documentation not look so ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override a function signature with the `.. autofunction::` directive. So to address your example, a function defined as `foo(x=0.97)` in module `bar`:

```
.. automodule:: bar

   .. autofunction:: foo(x=0.97)
```

And the resulting doc will use the signature provided instead of the interpreted version with the really long number.

You can do this equivalently with `.. autoclass::` and `.. automethod::` and the like. This is usage is documented in "Options and advanced usage" in [this part of the sphinx.ext.autodoc](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoexception) docs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Sphinx so I am not sure this will work, but my assumption is that `repr()` is used to determine the format of the documentation.  You can try subclassing `float` with a custom `__repr__` method that will return a nicer looking number to see if that helps:

```
class my_float(float):
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

>>> float(0.97)
0.96999999999999997
>>> my_float(0.97)
0.97

>>> def foo(x = my_float(0.97)):
...     return x+1
... 
>>> foo()
1.97
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was really hoping for a documentation side solution that didn't include modifying the actual project source.