# Avoid expansion of sys.argv keyword argument in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a class like this one

```
import sys

class ACommand(object):

    @classmethod
    def cmd(cls, argv=sys.argv):
        " Executes the command. "
        pass
```

When documenting this with Sphinx it expands `sys.argv` to its current value, producing something like the following signature

```
classmethod cmd(argv=['/path/to/sphinx-build', '-b', 'html', '-d', '_build/doctrees', '.', '_build/html'])
```

I find it more convenient to have `sys.argv` in the documentation than its expansion. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7228797/407651

Comment: The problem is that sphinx imports your modules/functions to generate documentation, so it actually _cannot_ see that the argument is really `sys.argv` it simply sees the _value_ that `sys.argv` had when the module was imported.

I'm not a Sphinx expert, but maybe there is some way to overwrite this kind of result specifying the value in the docstring(like `:param argv: Arguments ... (default: sys.argv)`)

Comment: @Bakuriu: it is not possible to override the function signature by changing the docstring. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12087750/407651.

Comment: @mzjn: That's why I said _maybe_. Anyway I think that such a feature would be useful. reST already provides `:param ...:` and `:type ...:`, so it probably wont be that hard to include it in the system.
You simply have to first get the signature of the function, then read the docstring and eventually overwrite the signature with the new information.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I retract my comment from Oct 2. You *can* override the function signature by changing the docstring. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12087750/407651.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a proxy object such as

```
class ListProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.list = l
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.list[i]
```

and then

```
@classmethod
def cmd(cls, argv=ListProxy(sys.argv)):
    " Executes the command. "
```

Or, easier, you could do

```
@classmethod
def cmd(cls, argv=None):
    " Executes the command. "
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
```

Comment: I've finally chosen the second option.