# Prevent Sphinx from showing a python function argument default value

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

In a package, I define a global variable `MyPackage.Data_path` in the `__init__.py` as:

```
Data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'database')
```

This variable is the default argument for multiple functions in my package. When I compile the automatic documentation with Sphinx, the variable is automatically converted into its value (the path string), but I need its name only to be printed in the documentation.

What Sphinx currently prints in the docs:

```
download_data(data_dir='/mnt/home/UserName/Path/to/data', ...)
```

What I need Sphinx to print in the docs:

```
download_data(data_dir=MyPackage.Data_path, ...)
```

I have tried with :meta hide-value: but it does not work (maybe I didn't use it right).
I know the best way should be not to have a similar variable, but it's very complex to change in this moment. I am planning on doing it ASAP.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482867/407651

Comment: Yes, it does! 
Here I found the best solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12087750/407651