# Sphinx cross-reference function as default keyword argument in call signature

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, cross-reference, sphinx-napoleon

Imagine I have a Python function called `foobar` with the following call signature:

```
def baz(x):
    return x + 1

def foobar(y, f=baz):
    return f(y)
```

Now I am using Sphinx with autodoc and napoleon to produce some documentation for this function. The call signature generated in the docs then looks something like:

foobar(y, f=<function baz>)

My question is: is there a way to make this a bit prettier, so that it just displays the name of the function? Or ideally a way to cross-reference baz?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482867/407651