# Override function declaration in autodoc for sphinx

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a module that goes something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

#: Documentation here.
#: blah blah blah
foobar = r'Some really long regex here.'

def myfunc(val=foobar):
    '''Blah blah blah'''
    pass
```

...and I have a `.rst` file that goes something like this:

```
:mod:`my_module` Module
-----------------------

..automodule:: my_module
    :members:
    :private-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

When I build the documentation, I get an html file with a snippet that goes like this:

> mymodule.foobar.**foobar** = *'Some absurdly long and ugly regex here'*
>
> *Extra documentation here*
>
> mymodule.**myfunc**(*val='Some absurdly long and ugly regex here'*)
>
> *blah blah blah*

Based on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365684/is-it-possible-to-override-sphinx-autodoc-for-specific-functions), I thought I could change it by altering my module to:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

#: .. data:: my_module.foobar
#: Extra documentation here
foobar = 'Some really long regex here.'

def myfunc(val=foobar):
    '''.. function:: my_module.myfunc(val=foobar)

    Blah blah blah'''
    pass
```

...but that didn't do the trick, and just appended the signature I wanted under the ugly one as part of the body. Does anybody know how I can properly override this?

*(I'm using Sphinx v1.1.3, btw.)*

Comment: I think my answer from 2012 still works, but there is now (Sphinx 4.0) an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482867/407651.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a module-level variable that is used as the default value of a keyword argument in a function. Sphinx displays the value (instead of the name) of that variable in the function signature. This problem is discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7228797/407651), and the OP has also submitted [an issue ticket](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/759) at GitHub about it.

However, you can work around this in two ways:

1. Override the signature in the .rst file by using `autofunction`, as explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368194/407651) to the linked question.
2. If the first line of the docstring looks like a signature and if the [autodoc_docstring_signature](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_docstring_signature) configuration variable is set to `True` (which it is by default), then Sphinx will use that line as the signature.

   So if you have a docstring that looks as follows,

   ```
   def myfunc(val=foobar):
       '''myfunc(val=foobar)

       Blah blah blah'''
       pass
   ```

   it should work in the way you want it.

   In the question, you have this first line in the docstring:

   ```
   .. function:: my_module.myfunc(val=foobar)
   ```

   This does not work because it does not look like a proper signature.

Comment: Can you do this for classes (more specifically, their constructors)?

Comment: That's cool, I opened an entirely [new question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786030/how-do-i-override-constructor-parameters-in-sphinx-with-autodoc).

Comment: You can make this even easier by putting the desired function signature in the `.rst` file after `autofunction` like `.. autofunction:: myfunc(val=foobar)` that way your actual docstring is more humanly readable. works for me

Comment: @MarkMikofski But then the function may not be ordered like you want when you use `.. auto*::\n    :members:`