# How to override constructor parameters in Sphinx with autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    """ Summary docs for my class.

    Extended documentation for my class.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.values = np.asarray(args)
```

If I use Sphinx with the `autodoc` extension to document this class like so:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
   :members:
```

...the constructor signature appears as **`MyClass(*args)`**. I would rather override this and document it as, say, **`MyClass(first, second, third)`**.

If this were a function, I could override the signature in the first line of the docstring. But that trick doesn't seem to work on a class docstring. So how can I override the constructor signature?

Comment: Hiding the real call signature from the users sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - the constructor is always called with a certain number of arguments. Whether it's `*args` or `arg1, arg2, ...` is an implementation detail, and could change at any time. There is no "real" call signature — the user should pass in what is documented as acceptable parameters.

Comment: There is a difference in behavior (towards excessive arguments, for example).

Comment: @LevLevitsky - if someone is using the API in undefined ways (eg. passing in excessive arguments), I don't really care. I certainly don't think it's worth having indirect and confusing documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that the best option for you is to do something like this:

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
    :members:
    :exclude-members: MyClass

    .. autoclass:: MyClass(first, second, third)
```

`MyClass` will have params overwritten and other members of `mymodule` will be autodocumented. 
You need to exclude `MyClass` using `:exclude-members:` because it will be included twice.
I think it's the simplest solution at the moment.

Comment: I'm using the `.. automodule:: mymodule \n   :members:` technique.