# Shorten long type names in autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

When `autodoc` lists a type in the documentation it generates, such as the `Bases` that a class inherits from, or type hints for a function parameters, it adds the type's module. For example, a function receiving a Tensorflow Optimizer would be listed as

```
f(opt: tensorflow.python.training.optimizer.Optimizer = <tensorflow.python.training.adam.AdamOptimizer object>)
```

This is really hard to read and redundant. Is there a way to suppress prepending the module name? Or another way to control how the type is listed?

**Edit:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12087750/4904699) helps fix this one function at a time. Is there a way to fix this for all functions?

Comment: You can `from tensorflow.python.training import optimizer` and then refer to the optimizer as `optimizer.Optimizer`.

Comment: @DYZ I've tried that, same result.