# Sphinx autodoc with parameter from a mocked module on readthedocs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

We are using readthedocs to document our open source project pandapower.

Since pandapower has dependencies to numpy and other C libraries that can't be built on rtd, we use the autodoc_mock_imports parameter to create mock imports for these libraries. This works great in general, but causes problems in the autodoc of functions that have np.nan as default parameters, for example [here](http://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/develop/elements/load.html#create-function). The default value e.g. for the sn_kva parameter is np.nan (see [here](https://github.com/lthurner/pandapower/blob/develop/pandapower/create.py#L447) in the code), but since numpy is imported as a mock module, it shows up as "sphinx.ext.autodoc._MockModule object".

Does anyone know of a possibility to avoid this?

Comment: You could provide the wanted signature as the very first line of the docstring. Sphinx will then use that as the signature in the output. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12087750/407651.

Comment: Yes that works, thank you! New version can be seen [here](http://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/develop/elements/load.html#create-function).
Seems like a valid answer, is there a reason you submitted this as comment?

Comment: Sometimes you're just not sure... Or in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the wanted signature as the very first line of the docstring. Sphinx will then use that as the signature in the output. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_docstring_signature.

In your case, the first lines of the function would look like this:

```python
def create_load(net, bus, p_kw, q_kvar=0, const_z_percent=0, const_i_percent=0, sn_kva=nan,
            name=None, scaling=1., index=None,
            in_service=True, type=None, max_p_kw=nan, min_p_kw=nan,
            max_q_kvar=nan, min_q_kvar=nan, controllable=nan):
    """
    create_load(net, bus, p_kw, q_kvar=0, const_z_percent=0, const_i_percent=0, sn_kva=nan,
                name=None, scaling=1.0, index=None,
                in_service=True, type=None, max_p_kw=nan, min_p_kw=nan,
                max_q_kvar=nan, min_q_kvar=nan, controllable=nan)

    Adds one load in table net["load"].

    ...

    """
```

Comment: A long signature can actually occupy several lines (it works without line continuation characters).