# Sphinx automodule shows types for function parameters. How to turn it off?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

So, I am using sphinx automodule directive to build documentation of a module, in which I am passing a dictionary as a default, named argument. The problem is, it lists out the types of all the variables in the arguments like this:

`lispereter.main.eval(x, env={'__name__': 'math', '__doc__': 'This module is always available. It provides access to the\nmathematical functions defined by the C standard.', '__package__': '', '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='math', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, origin='built-in'), 'acos': <built-in function acos>, 'acosh': <built-in function acosh>, 'asin': <built-in function asin>, 'asinh': <built-in function asinh>, 'atan': <built-in function atan>, 'atan2': <built-in function atan2>, 'atanh': <built-in function atanh>, 'ceil': <built-in function ceil>, 'copysign': <built-in function copysign>, 'cos': <built-in function cos>, 'cosh': <built-in function cosh>, 'degrees': <built-in function degrees>, 'erf': <built-in function erf>, 'erfc': <built-in function erfc>, 'exp': <built-in function exp>, 'expm1': <built-in function expm1>, 'fabs': <built-in function fabs>, 'factorial': <built-in function factorial>, 'floor': <built-in function floor>, 'fmod': <built-in function fmod>, 'frexp': <built-in function frexp>, 'fsum': <built-in function fsum>, 'gamma': <built-in function gamma>, 'gcd': <built-in function gcd>, 'hypot': <built-in function hypot>, 'isclose': <built-in function isclose>, 'isfinite': <built-in function isfinite>, 'isinf': <built-in function isinf>, 'isnan': <built-in function isnan>, 'ldexp': <built-in function ldexp>, 'lgamma': <built-in function lgamma>, 'log': <built-in function log>, 'log1p': <built-in function log1p>, 'log10': <built-in function log10>, 'log2': <built-in function log2>, 'modf': <built-in function modf>, 'pow': <built-in function pow>, 'radians': <built-in function radians>, 'sin': <built-in function sin>, 'sinh': <built-in function sinh>, 'sqrt': <built-in function sqrt>, 'tan': <built-in function tan>, 'tanh': <built-in function tanh>, 'trunc': <built-in function trunc>, 'pi': 3.141592653589793, 'e': 2.718281828459045, 'tau': 6.283185307179586, 'inf': inf, 'nan': nan, '+': <built-in function add>, '-': <built-in function sub>, '*': <built-in function mul>, '/': <built-in function truediv>, '>': <built-in function gt>, '<': <built-in function lt>, '>=': <built-in function ge>, '<=': <built-in function le>, '=': <built-in function eq>, 'abs': <built-in function abs>, 'append': <built-in function add>, 'apply': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'begin': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'car': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'cdr': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'cons': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'eq?': <built-in function is_>, 'expt': <built-in function pow>, 'equal?': <built-in function eq>, 'length': <built-in function len>, 'list': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'list?': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'map': <class 'map'>, 'max': <built-in function max>, 'min': <built-in function min>, 'not': <built-in function not_>, 'null?': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'number': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>, 'print': <built-in function print>, 'procedure?': <built-in function callable>, 'round': <built-in function round>, 'symbol?': <function standard_env.<locals>.<lambda>>})`

It does the same for other arguments too but this looks so ugly. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12082570/407651

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing

```
.. automodule:: module_name
    :members:
```

to

```
.. automodule:: module_name
    :members:
    :exclude-members: eval

.. autofunction:: eval(x, env=global_env)
```