# Shorten display format of Python type annotations in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, type-hinting, autodoc

Given the following function in a module called `mymodule` that I want to document using Sphinx with `autodoc`:

```py
from typing import Union
from collections.abc import Iterable
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

def foo(a: Union[str, int], b: Iterable, c: ArrayLike) -> None:
    """Do something useful."""
    pass
```

In the source, the function's signature is quite readable. However, in the documentation generated by `autodoc` the signature is displayed as

> khadl._util.foo(a: Union[str, int], b: collections.abc.Iterable, c: Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, numpy.generic, Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, numpy.generic]], Sequence[Sequence[Any]], numpy.typing._array_like._SupportsArray]) → None

which is just unreadable. The classes stemming from the `typing` module are displayed in a short form (`Union`, `Sequence`, `Any`), but for the abstract base class `Iterable` a unique identifier is generated (`collections.abc.Iterable`) and `ArrayLike` is even "unpacked" (`Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, numpy.generic, Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, numpy.generic]], Sequence[Sequence[Any]], numpy.typing._array_like._SupportsArray]`).

How can I configure Sphinx so that the function's signature is displayed in a readable way in the documentation, e.g. as in the source code?

Comment: Well your `c` input is very general. Does it have to be that many options?

Comment: You can do this by adding the signature as the first line of the docstring. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12082570/407651.

Comment: @astrochun Well yeah, I didn't just choose that type for fun. It's "anything that can be converted into a `numpy.ndarray`".

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't include `list` which is convertable to `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @astrochun `list`s are `Sequence`s.

Answer (score 10):

After some more digging I found that the [`autodoc_type_aliases`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_type_aliases) option can be used to achieve this. In order to make it work, you have to say

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

at the start of the module you are documenting. (This activates postponed evaluation of annotations as outlined in [PEP563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) <s>which will become the standard in Python 3.10</s>.)
You can then tell Sphinx how to print the annotations in your `conf.py` file.

```py
autodoc_type_aliases = {
    'Iterable': 'Iterable',
    'ArrayLike': 'ArrayLike',
}
```

(The key of each entry is the type hint as written in the source, the value is how it will be written in the generated documentation.)

Answer (score 2):

When I googled this question, I was looking for [autodoc_typehints_format](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_typehints_format) and [python_use_unqualified_type_names](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-python_use_unqualified_type_names) (`sphinx>=4.0 is required`):

```
# put this in your docs/conf.py for Sphinx
autodoc_typehints_format = 'short'
python_use_unqualified_type_names = True
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]