How to replace local file paths in autodoc generated documentation
I'm generating documentation for a python project with Sphinx autodoc. The project contains functions with default parameter values pointing to local paths. Is there a way to replace my own local paths with generic ones when generating docs, avoiding any errors due to non-existent paths?
Since I don't know how a solution to this is supposed to work, I've not tried anything except editing the generated docs manually.

If the first line of a function's docstring looks like a signature, then that signature is used in the generated documentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12087750/407651

This sounds like something to fix by changing your code, not by changing your documentation generation. Even if you change your docs, your actual functions will still have default argument values that make no sense for other users.

@user2357112 In this case, the default values refer to relative file paths specified in a config file. Is there a better way to implement that?

Have you tried using the autodoc-process-signature event function?
If not, you can replace specific local paths in your function signatures with generic paths when generating your documentation.
That way you won't have to manually do it. ( hope this helps )
